# Can I sell space buildings?

Tags: kittens-game

While playing Kittens Game, I noticed I had some buildings in space I did not need anymore because of their minimal effect. I would have selled them, but there wasn't an option to do so:

[image: Wait, what?]

Meanwhile, normal buildings *can* be sold:

[image: OK, this is getting really mad...]

Is there any setting to allow me sell things from the "space" tab? or is it not possible (without cheating)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, **no**, you can't sell space buildings at this time.

**However**, [it appears](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/issues/95/selling-space-buildings) as if this feature will be in an upcoming update.

Comment: As a side question, will/is this feature planned to be implemented into the game? If not, can I propose this to the developer?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Good thing that you asked, because I found additional information ;) In general, you can report issues on the [official bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/issues). I'm not 100% sure of the policy regarding posting feature requests on the tracker. The developers are also following the Kitten Game subreddit. So that is a good place to start a discussion.